# What are the coins used for?

Tags: last-man-standing

So I've started playing the new free to play battle royal game: Last Man Standing. It offers you to get cosmetics, like most games nowadays, that you can use to customise your character. You get these through their vanity crates.

These crates also drop coins. So far I have been unable to see how many coins I have and what they are used for.

What are they used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These coins are used to purchase certain locked skins you want. To find out how many you have go to the customise screen and the count is in the bottom right corner. If the item is locked you can then purchase it by clicking on the button underneath the count named Unlock for XXXX.

[image]